# Merge dataframe on closest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data for some experiments indexed by a subject ID and a date.  I'd like to join the data together, but the subjects may undergo experiments on different days.  Here is an example of what I mean.  Shown below are the results from two different experiments

```
SubjectID  Date        ScoreA
1          2016-09-20      10
1          2016-09-21      12
1          2016-12-01      11

SubjectID  Date        ScoreB
1          2016-09-20      1
1          2016-09-24      5
1          2016-11-28      3
1          2016-12-11      9
```

I would like to join the rows to the closest available date.  So ideally, my desired output is

```
SubjectID   Date1         Date2        ScoreA ScoreB
1            2016-09-20    2016-09-20    10      1
1            2016-09-21    2016-09-24    12      5
1            2016-12-01    2016-11-28    11      3
```

Note "closest date" is closest in absolute value.  How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: What would be the desired outcome if there are two equally close ScoreB dates to a ScoreA date? e.g. ScoreA date of 9/24 and ScoreB dates of 9/22 and 9/26? Or is it guaranteed that will never happen.

Comment: @B.Shieh That is not guaranteed.  In such a case, I would prefer the earlier date.

Comment: In your example, why is Date1=2016-09-21 associated with Date2=2016-09-24 if 2016-09-20 is closer to 2016-09-21?

Comment: @foglerit oh, good catch, that is just an oversight on my part.

Comment: Regarding the catch by fogelrit. That would mean the same ScoreB on 2016-09-20 would be linked with two different ScoreA's on 2016-09-20 *and* 2016-09-21. Is that the desired outcome? Another way to clarify: Should Date1 and ScoreA be the *base* data set (e.g. immutable) and then take the Date2/ScoreB that is closest each Date1/ScoreA? Or should Date1/ScoreA and Date2/ScoreB be given equal precedence? In which case what should be done in your example?

Comment: I haven't used it but may be you can look into pandas.merge_asof. Maybe try merging on date and groupby SubjectID?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you want with default pandas functionality, but it's straightforward to do it with a custom aggregation function:

```
def pick_closest(g):
    closest_date_loc = (g.Date1 - g.Date2).abs().argmin()
    return g.loc[closest_date_loc, ['ScoreA','Date2','ScoreB']]

merged = df1.merge(df2, on='SubjectID', suffixes=['1', '2'])
df3  = merged.groupby(['SubjectID','Date1'], as_index=False).apply(pick_closest).reset_index()
df3

   SubjectID      Date1  ScoreA      Date2  ScoreB
0          1 2016-09-20      10 2016-09-20       1
1          1 2016-09-21      12 2016-09-20       1
2          1 2016-12-01      11 2016-11-28       3
```

In this code snippet, the two frames are initially merged on `SubjectID`, generating all possible combinations of `Date1` and `Date2`. Then the `pick_closest` function selects the row with the smallest date difference between `Date1` and `Date2` for each `SubjectID`/`Date1` group.